# Deploying Java ESBs to the cloud

Tags: java, deployment, cloud, esb, mule

For a new project I'd like to use an Open Source ESB (Mule, OpenESB, ServiceMix etc) deployed to a cloud infrastructure (Google App Engine, Heroku, Amazon).

Are there any good resources on this and in particular issues such as scalability, state replication between cloud instances etc?  I couldn't find very much on this topic!

I'm aware that Mule has its own cloud offering (Mule iON) - but I don't think this is exactly what I am looking for.

Many thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to try out WSO2 Stratos ESB, one of the best performing ESB out there, with proven performance (in processing more than 1 billion transaction per day at eBay) The PaaS version (ESB as a Service) is available at https://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com/. You can try that out for free. This Apache Software Licensed open source ESB can also be downloaded & setup on an IaaS of your choice. For more details on WSO2 ESB, see http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/.